# Elastic Search Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working on a LDAP server. There is Elastic search on it.
I must send the query with some Javascript's code (in JSON format).

This is my query:

```
curl -xget wwww....
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "server": "serveur_name404"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to print all the result where "server" = "server_name" (ths field is server:server_name..).
Docs about Elastic search is too much small, I though. I've find some documentation but it's the same, no help for new user.. The example is too much simplistic.

This query return me all results, with any filter.

Ps: It's like in mysql "Where server = 'server_name404'"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all fields of an Elasticsearch document whose `server` field has the value `serveur_name404` you can achieve that by a very simple query.

```
curl -XPOST <cluster address>/<index name>
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "server": "serveur_name404"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Adrien If this answers your question, please mark it as an answer. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but it doesn't working. I just want the result when the field "server" = "server-name404". It returns me all the possibilities, without filter. Filter is not the approriate term there I think, it's more "facets", no? I've tried this query : {
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "p*"
    }
  },
  "facets": {
    "facets-type": {
      "terms": {
        "field": {
          "server": "server_name404"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: I just founding it. I'm an idiot, i was using xget instead of xpost. All client doesn't support xget with body. xpost y. Ty !

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -XPOST <cluster address>/<index name>
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "server.keyword": "serveur_name404"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)